# passing string from process to another working process C#?

Tags: c#, .net, process

i have two running processes, proc1 and proc2.
i need proc1 to send a string to running proc2 to func

```
useStr(string s)
```

how can i do it? can someone give me code exmple that I can use to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Process Means like Exe running as Notepad and Word, you need to send the String from Notepad to Word 2007. this is your Question.?

Comment: Try search before posting new questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106979/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-data-between-concurrent-threads-in-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360533/how-to-share-data-between-different-threads-in-c-sharp-using-aop

Comment: Google around and show some homework here before posting questions.

Comment: yes, it is two different Exes running, and they are not the same Exe

Comment: and it is not just two threads in the same process... the first one should send a string to the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create remotable object and pass or fetch current state or vales from this object. this object should be serializable ofcourse.

You can use windows service to achieve this.
Here are some of the references which points to same direction or can be considered as othere options.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/aa720494(v=vs.71).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4245/DevGlobalCache-A-way-to-Cache-and-Share-data-betwe